# .Net to Java to .Net Interprocess Communication using Java

Tags: wcf, interprocess, inter-process-communicat

I create .Net client (executable) which uses group of local services.
These services are 6 local services (out of process logger service, system diagnostic service, UI identification service etc.).
This pattern is mandatory.

The idea is to create group of local machine SOA's communicate with each other (on local machine domain only!). The most important aspect of the services layer is to provide best interprocess communication.

Since those services are valuable I don't want to limit my self to .Net/Windows world (I know Mono is good enough but don't want to rely on it at this point as solution).

Goggling around I could not find any real WCF equivalent in Java - all java frameworks lack the abstraction model WCF provides.

I would be happy to hear from the community how safe is interprocess communication (.Net-JVM-.Net) based on Java in Windows world.

And off course to hear about communication frameworks for Java

Answer (score 0):

if you want a SOA that is language agnostic then I would suggest using RESTful SOA, for .NET WepAPI would suffice, for JAVA consider JAX-RS http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

However for single domain only communication, TCP/IP Sockets is the simplest, easiest way to go.

Comment: @T McKeown from your answer I understand that there is not WCF for Java (from the abstraction POV). I guess this is the difference between to concept behind those technologies

Comment: WCF can bind to multiple protocols as well as handle WepAPI(RESTful) calls.  My point is the protocol is more important than a particular service choice.  Choose the most open protocol.

Comment: your point is interesting. What about security, services boundaries and other characters you'd like your service to have. Isn't selecting the most open protocol might give you too much flexibility?

Comment: well i don't know what restrictions you are imposing, but the protocol isn't going to expose/hide anything more than the runtime service that is processing the requests that are received from it.  For example if I created a WepApi MVC app (with just controllers) and my server was configured properly, there isn't any more risk other than what my code is executing.